# Is the Iran banking system cut off even from its neighbouring countries on good terms with it?

Tags: money, georgia-country, iran, kuwait, armenia

I'm hoping to travel to Iran in the next six months and [I'm aware that it's difficult to access "western" banks via ATM networks, bank transfer, etc](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30513).

But do the sanction even apply to countries that are "friends" with it in that part of the world?

I have friends in Kuwait, Georgia, and Armenia, who might possibly be able to help me get a bank account in their country or send me money after I get to Iran.

Is anything like this possible?

---

Yes yes I know I can carry huge amounts of cash in dollars or euros from my previous country and change it to a huge amount of Iranian cash after I arrive. I suppose I'm the only person in Stack Exchange who feels no qualms carrying large amounts of cash across border crossings I've never experienced before and around a country I've never experienced before for an unspecified period of time.

Comment: Why not get cash on your last stop before Iran?

Comment: (+1) Not what you are asking and I can easily see why it might not be practical for you but AFAIK US dollars and euro banknotes can be exchanged in Iran. Might be useful to know for other people.

Comment: Here is says you can take in unlimited dollars with you. Won't that be enough ? http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30513/how-to-take-money-to-iran?lq=1

Comment: @JonathanReez: I intend to travel for a month. Why do you not feel concerned about carrying large sums of cash around multiple countries and border crossings?

Comment: Guys I included a link to another question covering all these comments. I guess I'm just going to have to bloat my question with off-topic details ... \-:

Comment: Essentially your question is this: Do American and European economic sanctions directly interfere with Kuwaiti-Iranian banking and financial mechanisms? No, they do not. Although, I'm no lawyer and thus no expert, but, it does sound like something that is frowned upon by various alphabet agencies.

Comment: Oh well I'm not American so in theory I'm not supposed to be too concerned about various alphabet agencies. But not just Kuwait but also Armenia and Georgia. Armenia might be the least under direct US pressure but that's just a hunch.

Comment: I'm expecting at my level and style of travel that for one month if I take $700 I'll have a bit to change back when I leave, emergencies aside of course. But I didn't want to include that and make the question less useful for others.

Comment: Please add some references.

Comment: @hippietrail I usually put cash outside my wallet in a place where pickpocketing is impossible, when traveling to unsafe places. Although I have been strip searched a couple of times by morally dubious border agents...

Comment: Do too. For example, Iran is disconnected from the global SWIFT system used for almost all interbank transfers.

Comment: @jpatokal wow, perhaps i've underestimated how hegemonic western banking mechanisms are.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Even if Iran's neighbouring countries have good relations with Iran, the question is whether the banking system in the neighbouring countries is liable to the sanctions.

Cash withdrawals through ATMs between different banks are handled through [interbank networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interbank_network), many of which exist as standalone networks within a country (as the Wikipedia article linked to indicates). Cross-country / multi-region transfers are handled by interbank networks run by [Visa Plus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_%28interbank_network%29), [MasterCard Cirrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirrus_%28interbank_network%29), or other products from Visa / MasterCard that talk directly to their respective networks without going through an interbank network.

The main interbank networks and card providers are all run by Visa and MasterCard (primarily, except for regions [such as China where UnionPay used to be monopoly until recently](http://www.businessweek.com/news/2014-10-29/china-to-end-back-card-clearing-monopoly-u-dot-s-dot-opposed)). So for you to be able to use ATMs from a country with friendly relations with Iran, you'll need a bank that issues cards for its own country *not* on an American-owned network like Visa / MasterCard *as well as* on a card network that works in Iran.

According to the page on [Iran's banking system (Shetab)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shetab_Banking_System#Connectivity), it's an in-country network but with mutual agreements with banks in UAE, Bahrain, Qatar, Kuwait, and China. This means theoretically it may be possible to get bank accounts in one of these countries with a card that works in Iran, but there are caveats highlighted above that you need to watch out for and [YMMV](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ymmv). Your safest option is to check beforehand with any prospective bank whether their cards will work in Iran.

Comment: Great work! So I should look into Kuwait and China!

Comment: @hippietrail I think this means you need to open a bank account connected to *Shetab* in a country like Kuwait and transfer your money to it so that you can withdraw it via ATMs in Iran. If you couldn't open a bank account in one of those countries, I think your best option would be to bring cash with you. Make sure you read [this answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/6292/1588) too. Also note that you do not need to bring huge amount of money with you. Iran is a relatively cheap country for foreigners.